# common width to span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am working on a project, which I need to use anchor tag with text and images for this I have used ul tag, but the problem is I want to right align the image and left align the text inside LI.

here is my code

```
<div class="button-no-record">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>ADD NEW</span><img src="images/add_enabled.gif"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css

```
.button-no-record ul {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.button-no-record li{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:5px;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:29px;
height:29px;
width:103px;
border-radius:8px;
background:#e4e4e4;
color:black;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:.9em;
font-weight:bold;
}



 .button-no-record a span {
width:100px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:4px;
color:black;
vertical-align:middle;
 }
 .button-no-record a img{
vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

I want output like this

```
My Text   [Image]
My        [Image]
```

but currenty it is

```
My Text [Image]
My [Image]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
.button-no-record a span {
display: inline-block;
[...]
```

`<span>` is an inline-element, and so width won't apply for it. When you set it to `display: inline-block;`, it will apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `<span>` tag is an inline-element by default.
You can change this by adding

```
.button-no-record a span {
    display: inline-block;
    /* dirty IE7 hack (only if needed) */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button-no-record ul li span
{
float: left;
width: 200px;

}

.button-no-record ul li img
{
float: right;
}
```

Use the above style.

Answer (score 0):

Use float: left and float: right

```
.button-no-record a span {
width:100px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:4px;
color:black;
width:40px;
vertical-align:middle;
float: left;
 }

.button-no-record a img{
vertical-align:middle;
float: right;
 }
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PNZCj/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img id="image" src="images/add_enabled.gif">
```

CSS

```
#image {
    float:right;
    }
```

Comment: An answer without commentary is not really useful.

Comment: A comment without thought is not really necessary. This provides a possible way to fix the problem and it needs nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:block` to `.button-no-record a span`

Also why have you decalred two widths in `.button-no-record a span`